# transfer data after connect to android access point

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

i develop an android program that make an access point ant let other device to connect to it.

```
...
method.getName().equals("setWifiApEnabled"); // making access point 
...

...
int netId = wifimanager.addNetwork(wificonfig);
wifimanager.enableNetwork(netId, true);     //connect to AP
...
```

after connection process i need to send some data between devices but Host device and Guest device cant find each other!

how can i discover devices after making connection?

Comment: `make an access point `. Very nice. And only with one code line! `let other device to connect to it`. What do you mean? You can not other devices force to connect.

Comment: access point let other device to connect not force them!